# Apply nginx-ingress annotations at path level

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

We are migrating from a traditional nginx deployment to a kubernetes nginx-ingress controller. I'm trying to apply settings at a `location` level, but can't see how to do so with annotations.

For example, we had:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location /allow-big-uploads {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ...
  }
}
```

And we translate to something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m <-- this now applies globally
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /allow-big-uploads
            backend:
              serviceName: example-svc
              servicePort: 5009
```

Adding that annotation under the `path` section doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/) can only be set on the whole kubernetes resource, as they are part of the resource [metadata](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata). The [ingress spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#ingressspec-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io) doesn't include that functionality at a lower level.

If you are looking for more complex setups, [traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik) have built a [custom resource definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) for their ingress controller that allows more configuration per [service](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/cf7f0f878ac1d09338951c0d4461cd5ac4781e72/docs/content/reference/dynamic-configuration/file.yaml#L75). The downside is the definition is not compatible with other ingress controllers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 locations on the same host and you want to apply a setting on just one location , you can create 2 ingresses with the same hosts , and apply on the ingress you are interested the configuration snippet annotation:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

  more_set_headers "Request-Id: $req_id";
```

i have tried for this example and it works.

However, when i try to change the **client_max_body_size** via the configuration snippet , i get the error :

```
"client_max_body_size" directive is duplicate
```