# Configuring k8s nginx ingress to route React SPA and backend apis

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

My backend services is working great with ingress nginx.
I'm trying without success to add a frontend SPA react app to my ingress.

I did manage to get it work but I can't get both my backend AND front end to works.

My ingress yml is

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    
spec:
  rules:
    - host: accounting.easydeal.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
    - host: api.easydeal.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: docker-hello-world-svc
                port:
                  number: 8088
          - path: /accounting(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: accounting-srv
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /company(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: dealers-srv
                port:
                    number: 80
```

With this yml above i'm able to poke my backend like so -> api.easydeal.dev/helloword or
api.easydeal.dev/company/* and it work !.

However my react app (accounting.easydeal.dev) end up with a white page a console log with this error ->

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The only way i'm able to make my react app work is to change rewrite-target: **/$2 to /** . However doing so prevent to route correctly my other apis.

*I did set the homepage for the react app to "." but still have the error and I also try to set path to /?(*) for my front end*

here is my dockerfile

```
# pull the base image
FROM node:alpine

# set the working direction
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you check what HTML you are actually getting back using "View Source" or "Inspector" tab in Firefox "Inspect" window.

Comment: Have you tried to split `Ingress` on 2 resources? `accounting` with it's specific annotations and `api` like the one in the question?

Comment: @SameerNaik I have no page at all, no content

Comment: @DawidKruk When you say 2 resources do you mean creating 2 ingress service ? if so will this pose problem if i need both of them to be on the same domain ? I think this will make a different ip for each

Comment: @Pilouk that's correct. Please take a look on what I was trying to say: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/

Comment: @Pilouk I thought browser is getting some content back because of this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: @Pilouk I'm sorry I haven't noticed that your comment was edited. Splitting it won't assign 2 different IP's as [nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) is basing on `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`.  In the provisioning process the LoadBalancer is provided an IP address which is directing the traffic to your `Ingress` controller. This address is used in the `Ingress` resource.  You can have `one.domain` `Ingress` resource and add `second.domain` `Ingress` resource and they will be on single IP.

Comment: @DawidKruk Can you propose it as an answer ? Doing 2 ingress services sold this issue. Trying to give you some points here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by original poster:

> Doing 2 ingress services sold this issue.

The solution to this issue was to create 2 separate `Ingress` resources.

The underlying issue was that the workload required 2 different     `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:` parameters.

**Above annotations can be set per `Ingress` resource and not per path.**

You can create 2 `Ingress` resources that will be separate entities (will have different annotations) and they will work "together".

More reference can be found in the links below:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Apply nginx-ingress annotations at path level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750408/12257134)*
- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: Basic usage](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/)*

---

#### Being specific to `nginx-ingress`:

**By default** when you provision/deploy [NGINX Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) you are telling your Kubernetes cluster to create `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`. This `Service` will requests the IP address from the cloud provider (`GKE`, `EKS`, `AKS`) and will route the traffic from this IP to your `Ingress` controller where the requests will be evaluated and send further according to your `Ingress` resources definitions.

> **A side note!**
>
> `By default` was not used without a reason as there are other methods to expose your `Ingress` controller to the external traffic. You can read more about it by following below link:
>
> - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Deploy: Baremetal](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)*

Your `Ingress` controller will have **single** IP address to expose your workload:

- `$ kubectl get service -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller`

```sh
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.32.6.63     AA.BB.CC.DD   80:30828/TCP,443:30664/TCP   19m
```

`Ingress` resource that are using `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` will use that address.

`Ingress` resources created in this way will look like following when issuing:

- `$ kubectl get ingress`

```sh
NAME              HOSTS                 ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
goodbye-ingress   goodbye.domain.name   AA.BB.CC.DD    80      19m
hello-ingress     hello.domain.name     AA.BB.CC.DD    80      19m
```

> **A second side note!**
>
> If you are using a managed Kubernetes cluster, please refer to it's documentation for more reference on using `Ingress` resources as there could be major differences.