# kubernetes ingress server-alias only applies to one ingress host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, server-name

According to this doc (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-alias), I'm able to add additional server_name to the nginx config file.
However, it adds the extra server_name to all of my hosts, which cause conflicts for sure.
Is there a way to add server-alias only for one of my hosts? Say I only want to add 10.10.0.100 to my test1 host.
Ingress example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: 10.10.0.100
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: test1-service
            port:
              number: 8000
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: test2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: test2-service
            port:
              number: 8000
        pathType: Prefix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**You can split your `Ingress` resource on multiple objects (which will work together) to add `Annotations` to only specific `hosts`.**

> **`Annotations` can only be set on the whole kubernetes resource**, as they are part of the resource `metadata`. The `ingress spec` doesn't include that functionality at a lower level.
>
> -- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Apply nginx-ingress annotations at path level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749036/apply-nginx-ingress-annotations-at-path-level)*

---

Extending on the answer to give an example of how such setup could be created. Let's assume (example):

- All required domains pointing to the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` of `nginx-ingress-controller`:

  - `hello.kubernetes.docker.internal` - used in `host` `.spec`
  - `hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal` - used in `annotations` `.metadata`
  - --
  - `goodbye.kubernetes.docker.internal` - used in `host` `.spec`
  - `goodbye-two.kubernetes.docker.internal`- used in `annotations` `.metadata`

Skipping the `Deployment` and `Service` definitions, the `Ingress` resources should look like below:

`hello-ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello.kubernetes.docker.internal # <-- IMPORTANT  
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-service
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
```

`goodbye-ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: goodbye-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "goodbye-two.kubernetes.docker.internal"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: goodbye.kubernetes.docker.internal # <-- IMPORTANT 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: goodbye-service
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: Prefix
```

Above definitions will create 2 `Ingress` resources that will be merged:

- `hello-service` will respond for:

  - `hello.kubernetes.docker.internal`
  - `hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal`
- `goodbye-service` will respond for:

  - `goodbye.kubernetes.docker.internal`
  - `goodbye-two.kubernetes.docker.internal`

Running:

- `$ kubectl get ingress`:

```sh
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                                ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
goodbye-ingress   <none>   goodbye.kubernetes.docker.internal   localhost   80      36m
hello-ingress     <none>   hello.kubernetes.docker.internal     localhost   80      36m
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress NGINX: Annotations: Server alias](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-alias)*