# Nginx ingress configuration after migration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following kubernetes ingress configuration (nginx ingress controller) which works fine.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: test01-api-ingress
  namespace: test01
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api1
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api2
```

The above creates the following configuration (mostly omitted)

```
                location ~* "^/test01/api2\/?(?<baseuri>.*)" {

                        set $namespace      "test01";
                        set $ingress_name   "test01-api-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "test01-new-api-2";
                        set $service_port   "80";
                        set $location_path  "/test01/api2";

                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api2/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api2$" / break;
                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }

                location ~* "^/test01/api1\/?(?<baseuri>.*)" {

                        set $namespace      "test01";
                        set $ingress_name   "test01-api-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "test01-new-api-1";
                        set $service_port   "80";
                        set $location_path  "/test01/api1";

                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1$" / break;
                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }
```

For the upgrade of the nginx ingress controller, the following configuration should change (somehow). But when I apply it the ingress configuration:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1/(.*)" /$1 break;
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1$" / break;
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21/(.*)" /$1 break;
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21$" / break;
  name: test01-api-ingress
  namespace: test01
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api1
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api2
```

I get the following, which doesn't work properly, because it adds api1/api2 at both locations.

```
                location ~* "^/test01/api2" {

                        set $namespace      "test01";
                        set $ingress_name   "test01-api-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "test01-new-api-2";
                        set $service_port   "80";
                        set $location_path  "/test01/api2";

                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1$" / break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21$" / break;

                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }

                location ~* "^/test01/api1" {

                        set $namespace      "test01";
                        set $ingress_name   "test01-api-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "test01-new-api-1";
                        set $service_port   "80";
                        set $location_path  "/test01/api1";

                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1$" / break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21/(.*)" /$1 break;
                        rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21$" / break;

                        proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }
```

Any ideas of how will the configuration should be? How can I split it into the relevant locations?
thank you.

Comment: Hello. To have your `configuration-snippets` in specific locations you can split the `Ingress` resources based on `annotations` used. I will follow-up with an answer on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

I'd reckon the post ask the following question:

> How can I set certain annotations like `configuration-snippet` per **path**.

This specific setup could be resolved in either way:

- By splitting the `Ingress` resources per `Annotations` used.
- By configuring `Ingress` resource that would route accordingly on both paths.

---

#### Splitting the `Ingress` resource:

**You can split your `Ingress` resource on multiple objects (which will work together).**

> **`Annotations` can only be set on the whole kubernetes resource**, as they are part of the resource `metadata`. The `ingress spec` doesn't include that functionality at a lower level.
>
> -- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Apply nginx-ingress annotations at path level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749036/apply-nginx-ingress-annotations-at-path-level)*

Extending on the answer to give an example of how such setup could be created:

- `ingress-01.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1/(.*)" /$1 break;
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api1$" / break;
  name: test01-api-ingress-01
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test01/api1
        backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-1
          servicePort: 80
```

- `ingress-02.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api21/(.*)" /$1 break;
      rewrite "(?i)/test01/api21$" / break;
  name: test01-api-ingress-02
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test01/api2
        backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-2
          servicePort: 80
```

> Some side notes!
>
> Check if you have a potential misstype in your `snippet`:
>
> - `rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21/(.*)" /$1 break;` <-- `ap21` instead of `api21`
> - `rewrite "(?i)/test01/ap21$" / break;` <-- `ap21` instead of `api21`

After applying above resources you will have **2** `Ingress` resources:

- `$ kubectl get ingress`

```
NAME                    CLASS    HOSTS                        ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
test01-api-ingress-01   <none>   example.com                  localhost   80      42s
test01-api-ingress-02   <none>   example.com                  localhost   80      42s
```

---

#### Configuring `Ingress` resource that would route accordingly on both paths.

As said you can use following example to set the routing scheme for your `paths`:

The example of such setup would be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test01-api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api1(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: test01-new-api-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test01/api2(/|$)(.*)
```

---

I highly encourage you to check the official documentation about path matching:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress NGINX: User guide: Ingress path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)*

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress NGINX: Examples: Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

Comment: @Dawid Kruk why do I have to use the ```kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"``` ?

is this complatible with Kubernetes 1.13.4 ?

Comment: @user515576 I rewrote this paragraph. I included this annotation in case there were multiple `Ingress` controllers in your setup. Here you can read more about it: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/.  Please consider if it's possible to upgrade your `Kubernetes` cluster as it's 7 major versions behind the latest (1.20).

Comment: @Dawid Kruk the one ingress with two paths configuration worked fine, but when I updated the Ingress controller from 0.20.0 to 0.30.0, this configuration broke the controller functionality. Is there any other configuration that I can try?

Comment: You may want to check the changes happened from 0.20.0 to 0.30.0 and beyond. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/Changelog.md  There are some more changes in ingress syntax in recent versions. Ingress concept page tells more about it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types